# .net core register generic interface and retrieve them using getservice

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have interface `IOrder<T>` and `FurnitureOrder<T>` implements it

I need to register multiple implementations like this

```
services.AddSingleton(IOrder<Chair>, FurnitureOrder<Chair>())
services.AddSingleton(IOrder<Table>, FurnitureOrder<Table>())
```

Now I have need to retrieve all `IOrder` services and the types(e.g chair, table) to do some background work on it.
Can I get it using `GetServices` API?
if not possible, Please suggest if design changes needed

Comment: Can you elaborate on the background work you need to do and show some representative code? The correct solution is highly dependent on what kind of operations you need to do on the list of order services. And do you inject individual `IOrder<T>` instances, or do you solely need to use them as a list of services?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to introduce some common non-generic interface `IOrder` and register all services as it (something similar framework does for [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) registration and execution):

```
interface IOrder
{
}

interface IOrder<T> : IOrder
{    
}

services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IOrder, FurnitureOrder<Chair>>());
services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IOrder, FurnitureOrder<Table>>());
```

And then you will be able either inject them as `IEnumerable<IOrder>` into your  dependent class or use `IServiceProvider.GetServices<IOrder>()` call to resolve them.

Also note that next registration also should work:

```
services.AddSingleton<IOrder, FurnitureOrder<Chair>>()
services.AddSingleton<IOrder, FurnitureOrder<Table>>()
```

If you need generic registrations also you can automate non-generic registration with something like this (after registering all generic ones):

```
var serviceDescriptors = services
    .Where(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType.IsConstructedGenericType)
    .Where(descriptor =>
        descriptor.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IOrder<>));
foreach (var sd in serviceDescriptors)
{
    services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(typeof(IOrder), 
        p => p.GetService(sd.ServiceType))); // or add desciptor creating new based on existing one  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presume You mean during excecution of ConfigureServices?
You could do this:

```
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(IOrder<Chair>), f => new ChairOrder());

    var listOf = new List<ServiceDescriptor>();
    using var enumerator = services.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        var interfaceType = enumerator.Current.ServiceType;
                        if (!interfaceType.IsGenericType) continue;
                        if (interfaceType.Name.StartsWith("iorder", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            listOf.Add(enumerator.Current);                          
                    }
                    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                    foreach(var serviceDescriptor in listOf)
                    {
                        var interfaceIWant = serviceDescriptor.ServiceType;
                        var objectToUse = sp.GetRequiredService(serviceDescriptor.ServiceType);                            
                        //TODO:
                    }
```

Comment: Any particular reason to use enumerator for first iteration and `foreach` for second one?

Comment: nope :) just in flow, usually use foreach as it has that tab-tab shorthand, but then services has GetEnumerator method and thought for clarity, that IList<T> is an IEnumerable<T> was sort of besides the point to my mind